# How do I change my column type to interval in my Rails migration?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, migration, intervals, column-types

I”m using Rails 4.2.3 with a PostGre db.  I’m trying to change a column type in my table to an “interval” type, so I tried this migration

```
class ChangeTimeInMsInMyObjectTimes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :my_object_times, :time_in_ms, :interval
  end
end
```

but upon running “rake db:migrate,” I get the below disappointing error …

```
== 20160530164019 ChangeTimeInMsInMyObjectTimes: migrating ========================
-- change_column(:my_object_times, :time_in_ms, :interval)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "time_in_ms" cannot be cast automatically to type interval
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING time_in_ms::interval".
: ALTER TABLE "my_object_times" ALTER COLUMN "time_in_ms" TYPE interval
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:472:in `block in log'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:466:in `log'
```

How do I change my migration to get this to work?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/clarkdave/6529610

Comment: Besides putting hta tfile in config/initializers, are there other configurations I need to make?  I ask because I get the error, "NameError: undefined method `simplified_type' for class `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn'" upon using this file and then running "rake db:migrate".

Comment: That gist is trying to solve the wrong problem, you already have ActiveRecord support for the `interval` type, your problem is in the error message (column "time_in_ms" cannot be cast automatically to type interval) as is the solution (add an appropriate USING clause).

Comment: I don't understand.  How would I write my migration in the method you suggest that would run without an error and change the column type to "interval"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Postgres doesn't know how to cast an integer (I assume that's what `time_in_ms` is right now.) to an interval. But you can tell it how with the `USING` keyword. It takes an expression that Postgres will use to convert all the old values. So you can use this in your migration:

```
change_column :my_object_times, :time_in_ms,
              "interval USING (time_in_ms || ' milliseconds')::interval"
```

Note if you do this you should write separate `up` and `down` methods, because this way of using `change_column` isn't automatically reversible.

Oh also: you can ignore the gist from @Boltz0r. As @mu says it is trying to solve a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to

```
class ChangeTimeInMsInMyObjectTimes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :my_object_times, :time_in_ms, :your_current_type
    add_column :my_object_times, :time_in_ms, :interval
  end
end
```

Comment: This will delete the column including data on it, if you need to keep the data, see accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37578835/1845602